# Is it good practice to have 'naked' text in html?

Tags: html

Wasn't sure how to express this but what I mean is having things like `<h1>My name is</h1>Radu` as opposed to `<h1>My name is</h1><p>Radu</p>`. Obviously not the best usage of the `h1` element but I think that can be excused. So, should all HTML be wrapped by the appropriate tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not really good practice. In practice, it probably won't hurt, but it's technically "wrong", since the HTML spec doesn't permit naked text in the body. Browsers will forgive you and generally wrap them up in some other element (if you inspect the DOM tree using Firebug or something).

In XHTML it is completely forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

All text is "wrapped in" the `<body>` tag. There's no reason why it has to be wrapped any further. In your example, you're actually changing the "semantics" of the page by adding the `<p>` block; whichever one expresses what you want is correct.

Comment: Is this actually allowed by the doctype? (Assuming you want to properly conform to the HTML DTD and not just what the browsers accept.) The [body element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.1) doesn't seem to allow `PCDATA` (which was always my understanding), but then again, neither does the [p element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1), so perhaps I am reading it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the **DOCTYPE**

generally "best practices" are determined by the W3C and their validator service, if it passes validation for your intended DOCTYPE, I say you're good to go.  Many of the "Higher Level" DOCTYPEs require that most/all text nodes be wrapped in some form of DOM node.

Comment: Seems to pass through fine for HTML5 at least.

Comment: I'm pretty sure cat vomit would pass through fine in HTML5.

Comment: @Karpie - I'm not sure if that's a good or bad thing.. cats are generally quite small so usually it's easy to clean up.

Comment: Hah! seriously though...   Yes, It probably passes fine for your selected Doctype.